# HTML5 Websocket and ISA Proxy issue

Tags: html, proxy, websocket

I'm not an expert in ISA server, my issue is the following:

var wsUri = "ws://192.168.1.7:8887";

websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);

these two lines work fine.
But when I try to get 192.168.1.7 from the external computers I set up rule in ISA server:
websocket.domain.com -> (redirect to 192.168.1.7, bridging = redirect request to HTTP port 8887)

And the following doesn't work:

var wsUri = "ws://websocket.domain.com";

websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);

I see in ISA log "Status: 10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."
It seems that websocket doesn't transform message to HTTP so that it tunneled to the destination server.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've made workaround. Just installed another PC, gave it public static IP and deploy websocket on it.So I get PC out of my network and it doesn't deal with ISA.
I came to a conclusion that ISA 2006 do not pass original HTTP message and somehow corrupted it.